# "Validation failed for one or more entities" Error when changing default billing adress' street address

Tags: validation, exception, e-commerce, virtocommerce

Whenever a user tries to change his street address for the billing address, an exception occurs.
[image: Validation Error]

This is the stack trace:

```
[DbEntityValidationException: Validation failed for one or more entities. See 'EntityValidationErrors' property for more details.]
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.InternalContext.SaveChanges() +169
   System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyInternalContext.SaveChanges() +27
   VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Data.EFRepositoryBase.SaveChangesInternal() +41

[DbEntityValidationException: Entity Validation Failed - errors follow:
VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Customers.Model.Address failed validation
- Name : Only 128 characters allowed.
]
   VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Data.EFRepositoryBase.SaveChangesInternal() +548
   VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Data.BasicUnitOfWork.SaveChanges() +407
   VirtoCommerce.Foundation.Data.BasicUnitOfWork.Commit() +10
   VirtoCommerce.Client.UserClient.SaveCustomerChanges(String memberId) +84
   VirtoCommerce.Web.Controllers.AccountController.AddressEdit(AddressEditModel model) +1210
   lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +104
   System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +156
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__39(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +22
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +32
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3d() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass46.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3f() +225
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass33.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__32(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +34
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2b.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1c() +26
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1e(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +100
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +49
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecute>b__15(IAsyncResult asyncResult, Controller controller) +12
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +28
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +21
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +36
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.End() +54
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9651188
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Any idea if you can replicate this error on a clean build, considering I haven't changed anything relating to addresses, or any ideas on what would help?
Thank you.

[UPDATE] This also happens when changing the street address for the shipping address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer to this problem.
When changing the address field on both the shipping and billing addresses, the ***Name*** field would "blow up" due to too many characters. This would happen because it would keep adding ***BillingDefault*** or ***ShippingDefault*** to the end of the string every time the address was changed.

[image: Name Column]

In order to fix this problem I've changed lines 354:

```
if (!model.Address.Name.Contains(UserHelper.DefaultBilling))
   model.Address.Name += UserHelper.DefaultBilling;
```

and line 368 to:

```
if (!model.Address.Name.Contains(UserHelper.DefaultShipping))
   model.Address.Name += UserHelper.DefaultShipping;
```

This fixed the problem, hopefully it'll help you as well if you're running into it.